# Azure Function Apps - used logged in user's credentials to read/update Azure resources

Tags: c#, azure, azure-function-app

I have an Azure function app that can update the tags of Azure resources. Currently, I have an app registration that has contributor level access to my subscription, and these credentials are what the function app uses when reading and updating resources (I'm using [ResourceManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.resourcemanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet)).

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                            .FromServicePrincipal(/* app client ID */,
                                                  /* app client secret */,
                                                  /* tenant ID */,
                                                  AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var resourceClient = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.ResourceManagementClient(credentials);
```

I also have AAD authentication set up for my function app:
[AAD settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ve3Y.png)

Is it possible to use the logged in AAD user's credentials when reading/updating Azure resources instead of my app registration? This way,  I'm thinking that if someone sends a request to the function app to update tags but doesn't have the right permissions to the subscription, the request will fail.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm thinking that if someone sends a request to the function app to
>   update tags but doesn't have the right permissions to the
>   subscription, the request will fail.

You are totally correct. If the user doesn't have the rignt permission to the subscriptioin, the user will not be able to update tags. AAD users will only be able to access your function, but will not have the permission to update Azure resources.

Comment: This doesn't match the behavior that I'm currently seeing. If I authenticate through AAD as a user that should only have read level permissions to the subscription, they are still able to update resource tags through the function app.

Comment: @Michelle What is the permission name of your subscription?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean by "permission name"? I'm not familiar with that terminology.

Comment: @Michelle Sorry for that,I mean the role to your subscription

Comment: No worries. The app registration that my function app is currently using to read and update resources is set to the 'Contributor' role for my subscription. So as long as the user accessing my function app also has contributor level access, the behavior of the function app is fine - but if the user only has read level permissions to my subscription, then I don't want to allow the updates to go through. Let me know if that doesn't clear things up.